# Domain without WWW on Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, openshift, cloudflare, cname

I created an app on Openshift and added aliases.

My registrar doesn't allow me to add a CNAME without WWW. So I started using the Cloudflare DNS servers and added 2 CNAME records. In the records page it looks like this:

```
CNAME porta8080.com.br  is an alias of blog-porta8080.rhcloud.com   Automatic
CNAME www   is an alias of blog-porta8080.rhcloud.com   Automatic
```

I changed it like 3 or 4 ours ago and the domain status is already Active.

If I go to my website it won't be displayed if I omit the subdomain www. . But works well with www.

I wonder if I can do this with Cloudflare (with and without www.) and/or cloudflare is alrady routing for me. I got a free plan.

Thank you

**@edit**

Now I got a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. Any ideas on what could this be?

Comment: I use Cloudflare for [Qwk.io](http://qwk.io/) so it's definitely possible.  Maybe give it a bit more time?

Comment: Thanks , Mike. Is your CNAME settings similar to this by chance? can you say just by looking if I did something wrong?

Comment: Yup..  `CNAME qwk.io is an alias of qwkio-cedar.herokuapp.com Automatic
CNAME www is an alias of qwkio-cedar.herokuapp.com Automatic`

Comment: it's nearly working. I got a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS now

Comment: Well now it sounds like a web server problem, not a DNS problem..  Maybe run `curl` and see what it's redirecting to.  Some sort of infinite loop perhaps.

Comment: it's indeed the case. width WWW. it works fine, but without it gives me a redirect loop. `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 05:22:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Location: http://porta8080.com.br/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure.  Web server config issue.  Something is redirecting.  Perhaps ask this question on Server Fault, and include any necessary web config files, rewrite rules, etc.  It's not a DNS or CloudFlare issue though.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare Partner set-ups usually are done via a CNAME set-up. Unfortunately it doesn't strictly comply with an RFC to support a CNAME record on a root domain, accordingly you can either set-up your own CloudFlare account (you won't get RailGun if your host are not just a normal CloudFlare Partner but an Optimised Partner).

The way around this is either get them to support the Full Host set-up which CloudFlare now support or set-up your own CloudFlare account and use a nameserver install.